# logistic regression in web app

Tags: javascript, logistic-regression

I am looking to do logistic regression in a web app, but I cannot figure out how to do it with javascript. Is there a better way of approaching this. The app is coded in javascript with a heroku backend. I have been researching javascript logistic regression libraries to no avail. Everything I have found -- including regression-js and ml-regression offer support for logistic regression, but I need a method that returns regression coefficients as well as their respective p-values -- which is not supported by the two libraries I listed previously.

Comment: https://github.com/yandongliu/learningjs

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Based on the documentation for that library, it appears p-values are not included, nor are the coefficients. It seems like it just spits out accuracy. Am I missing it?

Comment: Its a point of start not a solution, read a lot, try to understand and perform your knowledge :-)